# Form with an image upload required

Tags: website-design, forms

I have a form to add an item.
I don't consider the item worthy of showing up in the application until an image is uploaded for it.
I can add a 'choose file' selector, but if other validation fails I can't repopulate the image itself.  I think this makes a very bad experience for the user.

What do you think is the best way to solve this:
Should I make it a two-step process?  That way all the validation happens first for the other fields, and then the image upload as a next step?  (If so, what should I do when the user leaves the second step prematurely)?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just verify the info on the front end with Javascript. You can use something like http://jqueryvalidation.org/ for the form. It won't submit unless it meets the validation requirements that you define.